# Powershell - modules not imported?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7.4

> The $env:PSModulePath environment variable contains a list of folder locations that are searched to find modules and resources. PowerShell recursively searches each folder for module (.psd1 or .psm1) files.

Based on this, I made the following structure

```
C:\my-own-modules
├───Globals
│       Globals.psm1
│
└───Wrappers
        Wrappers.psm1
```

also inspected `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\PowerShell\Modules` directory and "thought" this directory structure should work.

and I've added `C:\my-own-modules` to `$env:PSModulePath`

```
╰─$env:PSModulePath -split ';'

C:\Users\<user>\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
<some other default paths, excluded for brevity>
C:\my-own-modules #  my path is here
```

But the cmdlets/functions I defined in `Globals.psm1` and `Wrappers.psm1` doesn't seem to recognized. Even after `Import-Module * -Force`

Can someone point me what I am missing please? TIA

Comment: in its simplest form, the name of the folder that contains the module must match the name of the module, e.g.: C:\modules\myModule\myModule.psm1

Comment: do you notice anything wrong with the structure I mentioned above?

Comment: hmm it started working after I restarted my computer. I can see my own modules if I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable`

Comment: you updated the environment variable from powershell but probably missed to do a  WM_SETTINGCHANGE, so a reboot was necessary...